# Google App Script suddenly not working in Spreadsheet Form that was formerly working. Fonts Not Found

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Google app script is not working with error msg:

> "Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred" error console show
>   that fonts Not Found
>   "https/fonts.gstatic.com/fonts/css?kit=OtfYXvDq3H9yumjkQUKHI8eAddqfMek1TFqPTmdvyDSVdo-ucNhB"

The error msg states:

***fonts Not Found***

The app has a form which writes to the Google spreadsheet. As such no font styles are applied, but the form elements may be using some styles internally.  The script was working fine last week and the issue came to our notice today. As such no info is found re this issue on the Google app script docs. Can you please advise what is the issue here and how do I get it back to working again.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Marketing Spends'); 
  createForm_(app);
  return app;
}

function createForm_(app){
  var grid = app.createGrid(9, 5);
  var weekNumber = app.createListBox().setId('weekNumber').setName('weekNumber'); 
  var current_week = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'AEST', 'w');
  var currentWeek = app.createLabel('Current week: ' + current_week);
```

....... The createForm_ function adds all the required form elements(textbox, list, submit button) to the app.

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging to isolate what line of code is causing the error.  Use `Logger.log('My variable value is: ' + varName);` to print Apps Script info to the LOG, then VIEW the LOG.    Does the error occur when a sheet is opened?  When a menu item is chosen?  When a form opens?  When a form is submitted?  You need to narrow the error occurrence down to precisely when it happens.  If this is a bug, there is a site to report the bug, but they will need enough info to reproduce the error.

Comment: The error occur when try to show the form. The UI is created using  UIApp class which is now depreciated. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app

Comment: The more info we have, the easier it is to understand what is happening.  Maybe post the UI code so we could suggest how to replace it with something else?

Comment: function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Marketing Spends');
  createForm_(app); 
  return app; 
}

function createForm_(app){
  var grid = app.createGrid(9, 5);
  var weekNumber = app.createListBox().setId('weekNumber').setName('weekNumber');
  var current_week = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'AEST', 'w');
  var currentWeek = app.createLabel('Current week: ' + current_week); 
.......
The createForm_ function adds all the required form elements(textbox, list, submit button) to the app.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in your comment, the UI App is now deprecated.

[image: UI App Deprecated]

[Google Documentation - UI App Deprecated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app)

You must replace all of that code with the HTML Service.

Comment: Google action script started working again, even with the font not found console error.